# Javascript stop interval function async

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have the following script on my web page:

```
tid = setInterval(checkBounty, 1000);

function checkBounty(){
    var elapsed = (Date.now()/1000) - parseInt($(".bounty").data('created')) ;
    $(".remaining-time").html(valid - elapsed); //update remaining time until bounty expires
    if (elapsed> valid){
        $.POST('', {id: id}, function(){
           console.log ('bounty cancelled');
           clearInterval(tid);
         });


        //do an ajax post to cancel the bounty;
    }
}
```

This triggers the ajax post multiple times because it is executed async. How can I avoid that?

EDIT

I updated the question with the code I was using, forgot to add the clearInterval. I now realise it was the ajax that was not responding in less than one second and the function was being called again.

Comment: it triggers multiple ajax requests not because it is executed asynchronously, but because it is its behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with async.

You should use `setTimeout` instead of setInterval if you only want it to execute once

**EDIT** After rereading the question I think what you want is this (as answered previously as well):

```
var intervalid = setInterval(checkBounty, 1000);   // capture the id of the interval

function checkBounty(){
    var elapsed = (Date.now()/1000) - parseInt($(".bounty").data('created')) ;
    $(".remaining-time").html(valid - elapsed); //update remaining time until bounty expires
    if (elapsed> valid){
        clearInterval(intervalid);    // this stops the timer
        //do an ajax post to cancel the bounty;

    }
}
```

Comment: but I still want to update the remaining time every second. Ah, you mean have setTimeout just for the post?

Comment: Why don't you just simply call the ajax method first, and then start the timer? In the timer function you should only update the remaining time

Comment: @Kenneth: The remaining time is *before* the ajax call is done, not while waiting for the response.

Comment: So if I get it right: you want a countdown. After the countdown is finished you want to execute the ajax-method. Correct?

Comment: @Samson: No, I think that he just got the question wrong. Using setTimeout for the post doesn't help you.

Answer (score 1):

It triggers the AJAX call multiple times because you don't stop the interval when you don't need it any more. It will continue to count down and make the AJAX call each time as the condition will continue to be true.

Get the handle to he interval when you start it:

```
var bountyInterval = setInterval(checkBounty, 1000);
```

Then when you want to stop it (before the AJAX call), use the `clearInterval` method:

```
clearInterval(bountyInterval);
```

Comment: right, I should do the clearInterval right before going into the ajax?

Comment: @Samson: Yes. Well, as the call is asynchronous it actually doesn't matter if you do it right before or right after, but doing it before is more in line with the intention of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Clear interval to destroy the timer

```
var timer = setInterval(checkBounty, 1000);

function checkBounty(){
  var elapsed = (Date.now()/1000) - $(".bounty").data('created') ;
  $(".remaining-time").html(valid - elapsed); //update remaining time until bounty expires
  if (elapsed> valid){
    clearInterval(timer);
    //do an ajax post to cancel the bounty;
  }
}
```